# Updated jQuery from +1.6.4 to jQuery 1.10.2, jQuery generated page contents won't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I should mention that my experience with jQuery, jQuery mobile, and JavaScript is limited as I don't come from a web development background.

I just updated my version of jQuery from +1.6.4(grabbed jQuery library from a phoneGap tutorial and the JavaScript file had been renamed to just jquery.js, but the date of the file was well past the release date of 1.6.4, so I imagine it is +1.6.4). And downloaded the jQuery-migrate plugin to help discover deprecated code use.

Upon running my app, any page contents that were loading from:

```
$("#pageIDContent").html(htmlFromMustache);
```

in jQuery +1.6.4 where `htmlFromMustache` is created by calling:

```
var htmlFromMustache = Mustache.to_html(pageIDtemplate, pageIDdata);
```

where `pageIDtemplate` and `pageIDdata` are js variables which hold html strings for the DOM elements and were defined earlier in the same index.html. The content does not load anymore, since upgrading to jQuery 1.10.2.

The only error that I get from the jQuery-migrate plugin is:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js: Line 41 : JQMIGRATE: jQuery.attrFn is deprecated
```

And I cannot spot any instance of my using `$.attrFn`

Anyways here are some of the relevant chunks of code with one example page not loading correctly.

**JS scripts loading, defining survey page contents and data variables-- loading as html with use of Mustache further on:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone-no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
    <title>Our Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>

    <!--script src="js/jquery.js"></script-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>

    <script src="js/mustache.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js">app.initialize()</script>
    <script src="js/date.js"></script>

    <script>
.
.
.
    var survey1data = {happy:"",relax:"",sad:"",stress:"",angry:"",cheer:"",frust:"",irritbl:"",confdnt:""};
    var survey1template = '<h3>Think about how you feel right now:</h3>\
                            <h5>Right now:</h5>\
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">\
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
                                    <label for="slider-happy">I feel Happy:</label>\
                                    <input type="range" name="slider-happy" id="slider-happy" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">\
                                </div>\
                            </form>\
                            \
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">\
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
                                    <label for="slider-relax">I feel Relaxed:</label>\
                                    <input type="range" name="slider-relax" id="slider-relax" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">\
                                </div>\
                            </form>\
                            \
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">\
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
                                    <label for="slider-sad">I feel Sad:</label>\
                                    <input type="range" name="slider-sad" id="slider-sad" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">\
                                </div>\
                            </form>\
                            \
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">\
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
                                    <label for="slider-stress">I feel Stressed:</label>\
                                    <input type="range" name="slider-stress" id="slider-stress" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">\
                                </div>\
                            </form>\
                            \
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">\
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
                                    <label for="slider-angry">I feel Angry:</label>\
                                    <input type="range" name="slider-angry" id="slider-angry" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">\
                                </div>\
                            </form>\
                            \
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">\
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
                                    <label for="slider-cheer">I feel Cheerful:</label>\
                                    <input type="range" name="slider-cheer" id="slider-cheer" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">\
                                </div>\
                            </form>\
                            \
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">\
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
                                    <label for="slider-frust">I feel Frustrated:</label>\
                                    <input type="range" name="slider-frust" id="slider-frust" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">\
                                </div>\
                            </form>\
                            \
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">\
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
                                    <label for="slider-irritbl">I feel Irritable:</label>\
                                    <input type="range" name="slider-irritbl" id="slider-irritbl" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">\
                                </div>\
                            </form>\
                            \
                            <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">\
                                <div data-role="fieldcontain">\
                                    <label for="slider-confdnt">I feel Confident:</label>\
                                    <input type="range" name="slider-confdnt" id="slider-confdnt" value="5" min="1" max="10" step="1">\
                                </div>\
                            </form>';
```

**Within calling pageinit()**

```
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){

        $("#survey1").on("pagecreate","#survey1", function(){
            var html = Mustache.to_html(survey1template, survey1data);
            $("#survey1content").html(html);
        });
```

**Relevant Main page & Survey1 html contents**

```
<!--  MAIN PAGE   -->

<div data-role="page" id="main">
    <header data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <img src="img/evl_logo2.png" class="evllogo" width="100"/>
        <img src="img/uic_logo2.png" class="ui-btn-right" width="100"/>
    </header>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="notelist" data-role="listview"></ul>
        <a href="#survey1" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Tobacco Use Interview</a>
        <a href="#suspend" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Suspend</a>
        <a href="#bedtime" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Bedtime</a>
        <a href="#problemreport" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Problem Report</a>
        <a href="#demo" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Demo</a>
        <a href="#cancel" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Cancel</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
         <div data-role="navbar">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#anylink">Back</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#anylink" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#anylink">Go</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>

</div>


<!-- LINKED SURVEY 1 -->

<div data-role="page" id="survey1">
    <header data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <img src="img/evl_logo2.png" class="evllogo" width="100"/>
        <img src="img/uic_logo2.png" class="ui-btn-right" width="100"/>
    </header>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <p>Tobacco Use Interview</p>
    </div>



    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="survey1content">
        </div>
    </div>




    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#main">Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#main">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#survey2">Go</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've included the html of the main page because it's contents load perfectly fine compared to `survey1`, as can be seen in the pictures below:

[image: working main menu content]

[image: survey1 content not loading]

I should mention that I used to load the survey page with:

```
$("#survey1").live("pagecreate", function(){ ...
```

But have changed the page to load using $.on()

```
$("#survey1").on("pagecreate","#survey1", function(){ ...
```

Comment: I have solved the issue by deleting the second argument of the $.on() function... the contents now load correctly.

Comment: Pagecreate fires before pageinit.